# Numpy задать массив в dtype

Tags: python, numpy

Здравствуйте.
Суть проблемы: Необходимо создать массив numpy, в котором будет храниться 10 массивов размером 64 и у каждого этого массива будет дополнительно значение функции для этого массива.

```
dtype = [('array', int[64]), ('func_value', int)]
array = np.empty(10, dtype=dtype)
```

подобное решение не скомпилировалось.
P.S. подобная форма массива нужна для последующего sort по func_value. был бы благодарен за подсказку как еще это можно реализовать, если этот способ плох.

На данный момент у меня есть массив (array):

```
[[0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1],[0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1],[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1]]
```

И соответствующие ячейкам значения функций (func_val):

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Нужно отсортировать array в соответствии со значениями func_val (т.е значение func_val[0] соответствует функции от array[0])
Чтобы воспользоваться sort необходимо, чтобы данные имели, как я понимаю, такой вид:

```
dtype = [('array', int[64]), ('func_value', int)]
```

Comment: Вы можете привести небольшой (3х3) пример вашего `data set`? Пока что не понятно что вы хотите получить...

Comment: @MaxU data set представляет собой 10 шахматных досок с 8 ферзями (для генетического алгоритма), эти доски бинарно закодированы в массив длины 64 (каждой клетке - ячейка массива, 0 - пусто, 1 - ферзь). Изначально неправильно задал размерность массива, не 64*64, а одномерный 64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [103]: a = np.array([[0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0],[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,1]])

In [104]: fnc = np.array([3,1,5,2,4])

In [105]: a
Out[105]:
array([[0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1]])

In [106]: fnc
Out[106]: array([3, 1, 5, 2, 4])

In [107]: fnc.argsort()
Out[107]: array([1, 3, 0, 4, 2], dtype=int64)

In [108]: a[fnc.argsort()]
Out[108]:
array([[0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

плюс "reshaping":

```
In [109]: a[fnc.argsort()].reshape(5,2,2)
Out[109]:
array([[[0, 0],
        [1, 0]],

       [[1, 0],
        [0, 0]],

       [[0, 0],
        [0, 1]],

       [[0, 1],
        [0, 1]],

       [[0, 1],
        [0, 0]]])
```

---

Если я правильно понял задачу - вам надо создать 2D array размерности (10 x 65), где в последнем (или первом) столбце будет храниться значение функции.

Пример для 4 ячеек вместо 64:

```
In [75]: a = np.zeros((10,5), dtype='float32')

In [76]: a
Out[76]:
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32)
```

PS насколько мне известно Numpy не позволяет хранить различные типы данных для разных столбцов - для этого можно воспользоваться Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

In [79]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((10,4), dtype='int8')).assign(fnc=0.0)

In [80]: df
Out[80]:
   0  1  2  3  fnc
0  0  0  0  0  0.0
1  0  0  0  0  0.0
2  0  0  0  0  0.0
3  0  0  0  0  0.0
4  0  0  0  0  0.0
5  0  0  0  0  0.0
6  0  0  0  0  0.0
7  0  0  0  0  0.0
8  0  0  0  0  0.0
9  0  0  0  0  0.0

In [81]: df.dtypes
Out[81]:
0         int8
1         int8
2         int8
3         int8
fnc    float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: решение верно .

Comment: @Welaury, как на счет того, чтобы хранить значения функции в отдельном векторе?

Comment: тогда я не знаю как по этому вектору впоследствии sort делать. Еще вопрос: Как в параметр по которому происходит сортировка указать 5 ячейку (по вашему решению)?

Comment: @Welaury, приведите в вопросе пример данных - исходя из размерности доски 2х2 (4 вместо 64) для наглядности. Т.е. нужен входной `data set` и то, что вы хотите получить на выходе

Comment: добавил пример данных

Comment: @Welaury, в этом примере все строки равны - как ни отсортируй - заметно не будет...

Comment: скорректировал данные

Comment: @Welaury, я добавил пример в ответ...

Comment: @MaxU - день! 
прошу оценить "мой" ответ на другой вопрос.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/773841/python-Как-из-экземпляра-родительского-класса-создать-экземпляр-наследуемого-кл
опять - минусят. Что не так с моим ответом по сути?
Простите  -  не знаю как здесь обратиться лично, а не "на людях"