# Python. Как из экземпляра родительского класса создать экземпляр наследуемого класса?

Tags: python, ооп, классы, наследование

Есть программа на Питоне3:

```
class A:

......

class B(A):

.......


aA = A()
```

Как можно правильно и красиво преобразовать aA (экземпляр класса A) в экземпляр класса B?

Comment: Как вариант можно добавить в __init__ метод класса B возможность передать в качестве параметра объект класса A и аккуратно указать как именно нужно заимствовать атрибуты.

Comment: Не могли бы Вы привести пример такого заимствования атрибутов? Для этого все атрибуты нужно перечислять? Т.е. копировать код?

Answer (score 2):

Общего решения нет, нужно для каждых A и B смотреть и подбирать подходящий вариант.

Основные способы такие:

1). Просто подменить класс объекта.

```
a = A()
a.__class__ = B
```

после такой процедуры объект сохранит все собственные аттрибуты, а за аттрибутами и методами родителя будет обращаться уже к B, а не к A. И при явной проверке класса будет считаться экземпляром класса B.

2). Создать экземпляр класса B и перекинуть в него все аттрибуты исходного объекта. После чего пользоваться новым объектом. При желании можно дать ему имя старого.

```
a = A()
b = B()
b.__dict__ = a.__dict__.copy()
del a
a = b
del b
```

Оба приведённые варианта подходят не для каждого случая (например, если у классов разные и нетривиальные инициализаторы). И в сложных случаях велика вероятность что-то упустить из внимания и получить плохоотлавливаемую багу.

3). Как уже правильно сказали в комментариях, есть чуть более сложный, но и более надёжный способ - написать в инициализаторе логику, которая могла бы в качестве альтернативы обычному списку аргументов принимать объект другого похожего класса, и по его образу и подобию создавать свой экземпляр.

Comment: Александр, спасибо большое за Ваш ответ. Не могли бы Вы, чуть подробнее описать третий вариант. Можно ли привести пример? Как в этом случае можно скопировать все поля не перечисляя их по одному?

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Представьте `A=object`, а реализация `B` никак не ограничена. В общем случае, наличие `object()` не достаточно, чтобы создать `B()`.

Конкретные классы `B` могут конечно определять конструкторы, которые `A` принимают. К примеру, `collections.Counter` можно создать из словаря (`dict`):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> d = dict(a=1, b=0)
>>> +Counter(d)
Counter({'a': 1})
```

Comment: может человек что то хотел спросить про утиную типизацию? и про то, можно ли добавить методов в объект "на лету".
хотя - согласен - интересоваться что именно хотел спросить человек - себе дороже

Comment: @VasylKolomiets: не нужно людей в заблуждение вводить и минусы ставить другим ответам, только потому что я вам указал: *"ссылка на решение не является ответом. Изложите суть решения прямо в ответе или просто как комментарий публикуйте ссылки"* -- ещё раз: если не согласны с этой политикой, обращайтесь на Мету. Из мести минусы не нужно ставить -- это вводит в заблуждение будущих читателей.

Comment: из мести? что "надо", а что "не надо" позвольте каждому человеку решать самостоятельно. Если вы считаете что это месть, это ваше право. Я считаю ответ "никак" не вполне корректным.
Даже если я ошибаюсь - это так же право каждого человека.
Закон больших чисел покажет вашу правоту или неправоту.
Я ж здесь не один "читатель". Заодно и я увижу что правильно.
__________________________________________ Вас действительно беспокоит один минус при ваших 32к?
Или вы верите что кроме нас двоих этот пост никто не прочтет?
Попробуйте ответить себе о причине вашего желания поучать и всем станет легче.

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы из объекта одного класса сделать "работающий" объект другого класса, придется добавлять методы и менять тип класса. Как подменить тип - вам рассказали.
Одним из трех способов можно добавлять [методы в экземпляр класса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object-instance):

```
class A:
    def back_print(a: str) -> None:
        print(a[::-1])

class B(A):
    def foo(self,a,b):
        print(a+b)
    
b = B()
print(type(b))

# строим функцию, которая будет добавлена как метод "а-ля" класс B()

def foo(self,a,b):
    print(a, '+', b)
```

## 1й способ добавить метод в объект динамически

```
aA = A()     
aA.foo = foo.__get__(aA)
aA.foo(2,3)
print(type(aA))

# подменяем тип:
aA.__class__ = type(b)
if type(aA)==type(b):
    print(' type(aA)==type(b) ')
```

## 2й способ добавить метод в объект динамически

```
def bind(instance, method):
    def binding_scope_fn(*args, **kwargs): 
        return method(instance, *args, **kwargs)
    return binding_scope_fn

bA = A()
bA.foo = bind(bA, foo)

aA.foo(2,3)
print(type(bA))
```

## 3й способ добавить метод в объект динамически

```
import types
cA = A()   
cA.foo = types.MethodType(foo, cA)
cA.foo(2,3)
print(type(cA))
```

## подменяем тип:

```
cA.__class__ = type(b)
cA.foo(2,3)
b.foo(2,3)
if type(cA)==type(b):
    print(' type(cA)==type(b) ')
```

как добавлять свойства *в класс* можно [прочесть здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325673/how-to-add-property-to-a-class-dynamically) на кривом русском:

думается, что инкапсулированные свойства - это просто "специальные методы", которые можно добавить аналогично. Пусть меня поправят "отцы", если я не прав.

## Свойства-переменные добавляются легко:

```
cA.pro = 7
print(f'cA.pro: {cA.pro}')
```

на выходе получите:

```
cA.pro: 7
```

В заключение - как [добавлять динамически методы в класс](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929543/how-can-i-dynamically-create-class-methods-for-a-class-in-python)
Так что теперь у вас есть все для "партизанского патчинга" на лету!
Удачи.

Comment: Василий, только что увидел ваш ответ. Ещё не разобрался, но уже хочу Вам сказать - большое спасибо.

Comment: Василий, только что опробовал Ваш 3-й вариант. В результате я получил экземпляр родительского класса, а не класса потомка. Задача была: как из экземпляра родительского класса сделать экземпляр наследуемого класса. Имелось ввиду, что наследуемый класс имеет всеи поля родительского класса плюс дополнительные поля. Как сдесь следует поступить?

Comment: @DmitryVil  - а строчку подмены типа сделали:
_____ аналогичную этой:   cA.__class__ = type(b)    ?
тип все равно надо подменить "вручную" ... все три способа только добавляют методы.